# Sublime Text 3 - Different Anacondas?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, anaconda, sublime-anaconda

I just got myself ST3 and followed some tutorials, all of which recommended to install Anaconda via the ST3 package control:
**CTRL+SHIFT+P -> "install" -> "anaconda_go"**.
I then tried to use the packages that come with anaconda (i.e. NumPy) through:

```
import numpy as np
```

This results in:

```
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

Turns out that the Continuum analytics package I wanted called Anaconda is not the one I got (the ST3 extension). So I instead got myself:
**CTRL+SHIFT+P -> "install" -> "conda"**.
But again, I am unable to use the packages that come with it, like Numpy.
How can I use the packages that come with the [conda installer](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs)?

Comment: So, it doesn't make sense to me that you would use ST3 package control to install Anaconda. ST3 package control is for controlling *SublimeText plugins*, and Anaconda is a Python distribution, not a Python package anyway. When I looked up "anaconda_go" and "sublime text" I got a hit for some [Go-Lang lineter](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda_go) and a beefy [Python IDE extension for sublime](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda) which doesn't seem to be related to the  Anaconda distribution. You should just use the Anaconda installer from the website...

Comment: Note, even the tags "anaconda" and "sublime-anaconda" on StackOverflow are for totally unrelated things.

Comment: Hence the title! There are two things called Anaconda related to python: the ST3 IDE extension and the Continuum Analytics package distribution. I got confused! My question is: How can I get the Continuum Analytics Anaconda to work with my ST3?

Comment: Well, it begins with downloading the Anaconda *python* distribution. Then pointing your SublimeText to that interpreter. Again, Anaconda is a whole *distribution* that inlcudes an interpreter.

Comment: It seems to me, however, that I should be able to set up the anaconda distribution from within ST3... [Anaconda with ST3](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/sublime)

Comment: No, that doesn't make *any sense at all*. ST3 is a text editor. If it has a package management system, it would be for ST3 packages. Why would it work with Anaconda, the Python distribution, that doesn't have anything to do with ST3?

Comment: Refer to link in previous comment. What I overlooked was that the conda ST3 package already requires an Anaconda installation in the default install path. Should be all sorted now.